# What's the syntax for this kind of graph using ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: Here is the graph]

How can I make a graph like that? Thank you.

If I have two dataframes like this [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXCrD.png), and their topics are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Frequency = c(300, 0, 600, 900, 0, 1000, 700, 
                           0, 300, 400, 0, 1400, 1600, 6500,
                           0, -250, -500, -400, -600, -1300, 
                           0, -1150, -100, 0, -200, 0, -2500, 
                           -2500),
                 Stream = rep(c("Ne", "Pri"), each = 14),
                 country = c("Argentina", "Brazil", "Canada", 
                           "France", "Germany", "India", 
                           "Indonesia", "Italy", "Mexico", 
                           "Phillipines", "Spain", "Thailand", 
                           "United Kingdom", "United States"))

ggplot(df, aes(Frequency, country, fill = Stream)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.6) +
  labs(y = "") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-2500, 0, 2500, 3750, 5000, 6250),
                     labels =c(250, 0, 2500, 3750, 5000, 6250),
                     limits = c(-2600, 7000)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank())
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

If I have two data frames like this:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(topic = c("design", "game", "hardware", "price"),
                  n = c(80, 1695, 29, 53))

df1
#>      topic    n
#> 1   design   80
#> 2     game 1695
#> 3 hardware   29
#> 4    price   53

df2 <- data.frame(topic = c("design", "game", "hardware", "price"),
                  n = c(400, 1235, 290, 107))

df2
#>      topic    n
#> 1   design  400
#> 2     game 1235
#> 3 hardware  290
#> 4    price  107
```

Then I can simply `rbind` them together, negating the `n` column on `df2` first and adding a column to show which data frame each value came from:

```r
df3 <- rbind(df1, within(df2, n <- -n))
df3$origin <- rep(c("df1", "df2"), each = nrow(df1))
```

And when I plot, I add `abs` as a labeller in `scale_x_continuous to remove the negative symbols on the left half of the plot.

```r
ggplot(df3, aes(n, topic, fill = origin)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = abs)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, if I need to use 2 dataframes with the same vairables, what should I do?

Comment: You should edit your question to include your data. I have answered the question exactly as it was asked by going to the effort to make up a data frame. If I make up two data frames to make another example, you will most likely come back and say "but how do I apply this to my data frames?". That is why it is best to make a reproducible example. You get your answer more quickly, with less requests for clarification, and less work and frustration on the answerer's part if you paste your actual data into the question. Try `dput(my_data_frame)` in the console to get reproducible data.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and patience. I'm new to R and stackoverflow and just asked my friend how to mark the answer as accepted.